# Load same class with different set of properties

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to implement one of the scenario where I have a requirement to load the same class with different set of properties in different application contexts in a single JVM.

e.g. (Ignore petty errors this is just to give a high-level idea)

Class:

```
public class TestMe {
   private String name;

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name=name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

My properties file should be something like:

```
context1.prop.name=Hello
context2.prop.name=World
```

Bean definition would be something like:

```
<beans>
   <bean id="testMe" class="TestMe">
      <property name="name" value="${prop.name}" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

So when context1 will be loaded all properties prefixed with context1 will be used to build the context.

And when context2 will be loaded all properties prefixed with context2 will be used to build the context.

In the end I will have a map of 2 contexts in my app containing beans with same ids.

I did implement the spring XML config version of this using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. But I want to get rid of xmls and stick with annotations only. Can anyone suggest how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate your context1/context2 to two properties files and pass info about which one to use using environment variable. Then you have to configure PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer like:

```
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocations(new ClassPathResource[]{
            new ClassPathResource("config/"+System.getenv("env") + ".properties"),
    });

    return properties;
}
```

so it will load for example config/context1.properties file. You can pass this variable using `-Denv=context1` while running app.

2nd solution can be using profiles and spring built in support for loading specific files ( like if you use 'test' profile it will load application-test.properties automatically for you)

3rd - yaml support - take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Can I have a sample to ascertain and note no XML configs.