# DRYly configuring "the same" class differently in different user classes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, configuration, autowired

### Question

Let's say that I have a class that takes a lot of constructor parameters which are mostly things that I want to be configurable through the application's non-hardcoded configuration (e.g. `application.yml` in Spring Boot):

```java
public class WantThisConfigured {
    public WantThisConfigured(String configValue1, Integer configValue2, ... many more ...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I have several Spring Components that need to use instances of this class and importantly, it should be possible to have a different configuration for it in each Component - pseudocode:

```java
public class ComponentThatNeedsToUseIt1 {
    @ConfigureItSomehow(for use in component 1)
    private WantThisConfigured wantThisConfigured;
    ...
}

public class ComponentThatNeedsToUseIt2 {
    @ConfigureItSomehow(for use in component 2)
    private WantThisConfigured wantThisConfigured;
    ...
}

...
```

What would be the least repetitious way to achieve this?

### Possible approaches I have considered

#### Repetitious option 1: Separate Bean classes for each case, configuration via lots of `@Value` annotations

This is probably the simplest option: Just create a new `@Bean`-annotated class for each possible usage of the class and configure it via `@Value` annotations, then have these Beans autowired into the classes that need them by type. You can see how this gets repetitious fast for a large number of configuration values, as I'll need a lot of Beans that all look the same except for different sections in their `@Value` annotations, e.g. `@Value("component1.wantthisconfigured.value1")`, `@Value("component1.wantthisconfigured.value2")`, ... for the first component, then `@Value("component2.wantthisconfigured.value1")`, `@Value("component2.wantthisconfigured.value2")`, ... for the second, and so on.

This can be made less repetitious by subclassing so that the `@Value` annotations and their associated variables are the only things that need to be repeated within each class, but still.

#### Repetitious option 2: Separate Beans wired by name, configuration via lots of `@Value` annotations

Variation on option 1 except we wire Beans in by name instead of by type, so we can get away with just having different methods that produce them for the different cases instead of separate classes. Otherwise the amount of repetition is about the same.

#### Less repetitious option: `@ConfigurationProperties` on subclasses

I guess what could work would be to define a class that holds all the configuration values named as they should appear in the config, then create subclasses of that class and annotate each with `@ConfigurationProperties("componentN.wantthisconfigured")` so that no `@Value` annotations are necessary. When I tried this, there were several issues that make life harder, such as `@ConfigurationProperties` either working via getters and setters (=> need another mechanism to actually instantiate the `WantThisConfigured` instance on demand) or via `@ConstructorBinding` which, AFAICT, needs a constructor in the derived class so again there is repeated boilerplate. There would also always be the remaining repetitious aspect in needing all those different subclasses for each component, plus I'm not sure how idiomatic this is, considering one has to first enable configuration properties globally to make this work at all, SpEL won't work with this, etc.

#### Impossible option: "Indirect parametrization" (e.g. via `@Value` constructing POJO)

What I'd really want, but don't think is possible in Spring, would be something that allows me to annotate the variables holding the `WantThisConfigured` instances in the classes where they are used and only determine which config prefix to load their configs from there, e.g.:

```java
public class ComponentThatNeedsToUseIt1 {
    @ValuesFrom("component1.wantthisconfigured");
    private WantThisConfigured wantThisConfigured;
    ...
}
```

I thought one workaround to make this work might have been to try and make `@Value` deserialize into a POJO that holds all the config options and takes care of providing an instance of `WantThisConfigured`, but as the answers to the question [Spring possibility to @Value on a Pojo / object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65365181/21564193) explain, this isn't possible.

### Related questions

- [How to declare multiple object with same class but using different properties in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56764728/21564193) is effectively the same question, except its author seems fine with some repetition. If I were to implement [its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56764989/21564193) in the scenario described above, I'd have to repeat all the configuration parameters for both `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated methods, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.
- The same for [Autowire 2 instances of the same class in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62641093/21564193) where you can actually see the repetition I'm trying to avoid in the accepted answer.
- [Load same class with different set of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26542150/21564193) is also similar, except its author wants to have the parts of the configuration to use depend on the *Application Context* (a term with a clear definition in Spring, different from "context" in the general sense in which I use it here).